# How to use predict on a test set?

Tags: r, model

I am going to eventually do multivariate regression for a vary large set of predictors. To make sure that I am putting the data in correctly and getting expected results with a toy model. However when I try to use predict it does not predict on the new data, also since the size of the new data is different from the training set it gives me an error.

I have looked and tried various things on the Internet and none have worked. I am almost ready to give up and write my own functions but I am also building models with the please package, which I am guessing probably calls this internally already so I want to be consistent. Here is the short script I wrote:

```
  x1<-c(1.1,3.4,5.6,1.2,5,6.4,0.9,7.2,5.4,3.1) # Orginal Variables 
  x2<-c(10,21,25,15.2,18.9,19,16.2,22.1,18.6,22)
  y<-2.0*x1+1.12*x2+rnorm(10,mean=0,sd=0.2) # Define output variable 
  X<-data.frame(x1,x2)
  lfit<-lm(y~.,X) # fit model 
  n_fit<-lfit$coefficients

  xg1<-runif(15,1,10) # define new data 
  xg2<-runif(15,10,30)
  X<-data.frame(xg1,xg2)# put into data frame 

  y_guess<-predict(lfit,newdata=X) #Predict based on fit 
  y_actual<-2.0*xg1+1.12*xg2 # actual values because I know the coefficients
  y_pred=n_fit[1]+n_fit[2]*xg1+n_fit[3]*xg2 # What predict should give me  based on fit
  print(y_guess-y_actual) #difference check
  print(y_guess-y_pred)
```

These are the values I am getting and the error message:

```
  [1]  -4.7171499 -16.9936498   6.9181074  -6.1964788 -11.1852816  0.9257043 -13.7968731  -6.6624086  15.5365141  -8.5009428
  [11] -22.8866505   2.0804016  -1.8728602 -18.7670797   1.2251849 
  [1]  -4.582645 -16.903164   7.038968  -5.878723 -11.149987   1.162815 -13.473351  -6.483111  15.731694  -8.456738
  [11] -22.732886   2.390507  -1.662446 -18.627342   1.431469
  Warning messages:
  1: 'newdata' had 15 rows but variables found have 10 rows 
  2: In y_guess - y_actual :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
  3: In y_guess - y_pred :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The predicted coefficient are 1.97 and 1.13 and intercept -0.25, it should be 0 but I added noise, this would not cause a big discrepancy as it is. How do I get it so I can predict an independent test set.

Comment: you need the same names in the `data.frame` used for `newdata` in `predict()`, eg. `X<-data.frame(x1=xg1,x2=xg2)`

Answer (score 4):

From the help - documentation, `?predict.lm`:

`"Variables are first looked for in newdata and then searched for in the usual way (which will include the environment of the formula used in the fit)."`

The `data.frame()`, created in: `X <- data.frame(xg1, xg2)`, has different names: (xg1, xg2). `predict()` cannot find the original names (x1, x2) and will then search for the correct variables in the formula instead. The result is that you obtain the fitted values from your original data.

Solve this by making your names in the newdata consistent with the original:
`X <- data.frame(x1=xg1, x2=xg2)` :

```
x1 <- c(1.1, 3.4, 5.6, 1.2, 5, 6.4, 0.9, 7.2, 5.4, 3.1) # Orginal Variables 
x2 <- c(10, 21, 25, 15.2, 18.9, 19, 16.2, 22.1, 18.6, 22)
y <- 2.0*x1 + 1.12*x2 + rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=0.2) # Define output variable 
X <- data.frame(x1, x2)
lfit <- lm(y~., X) # fit model 
n_fit <- lfit$coefficients

xg1 <- runif(15, 1, 10) # define new data 
xg2 <- runif(15, 10, 30)
X <- data.frame(x1=xg1, x2=xg2) # put into data frame 

y_guess <- predict(lfit, newdata=X) #Predict based on fit 
y_actual <- 2.0*xg1 + 1.12*xg2 # actual values because I know the coefficients
y_pred = n_fit[1] + n_fit[2]*xg1 + n_fit[3]*xg2 # What predict should give me  based on fit

> print(y_guess - y_actual) #difference check
           1            2            3            4            5            6            7            8            9           10           11           12           13 
-0.060223916 -0.047790535 -0.018274280 -0.096190467 -0.079490487 -0.063736231 -0.047506981 -0.009523583 -0.047774006 -0.084276807 -0.106322290 -0.030876942 -0.067232989 
          14           15 
-0.023060651 -0.041264431 
> print(y_guess - y_pred)
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```